# django prefetch_related and select_related on parent table

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following db structure:

```
catogory
   id
   name
   parent_id

class Category(models.Model)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
  parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to fetch all categories and their parent.

If I do:

```
Category.objects.select_related("parent").filter(pk__in=[ids])
```

it would just return the parent of the first level.

How can I retrieve the parents of all level with minimum db calls?

My approach is to build a new non-db-model objects e.g:
CategorySerializer that will transfer those Category models to non db ones so the logic layer could use it

Comment: What if you replace `.filter` with `.all()`?

Comment: but I want to filter the categories to fetch in first time

Comment: I see. And you want the grandparents, etc., of those ids in your list. Correct?

Comment: exactly, so when I loop over the results later it will not make a db call. architecture wise, I don't want the logic layer to make db calls

Comment: You almost need to make some sort of recursive call.

Comment: How many Categories do you have and how many levels deep will the parent relationships go?

Comment: so now I have only 3 levels, but I would like it to be dynamic

Comment: If you're storing a tree-like structure (no loops) and you need to pull all the parents in a single SQL query, without using recursion (in terms of some fancy raw SQL), then you should consider implementing some other tree-storage schema, like *materialized path* or *nested sets*. Search for those terms to see what I mean - there are a lot of articles on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you created a function that you can call recursively until there are no more parents left

```
def get_categories(ids):
    ids = list(Category.objects.select_related("parent").filter(pk__in=[ids]).values_list('parent_id', flat=True))
    if len(ids) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return ids + get_categories(ids)
```

So start with this call

```
all_parent_ids = []
for category in list(Category.objects.all()):
    all_parent_ids.append(get_categories(category.parent_id))
```

I haven't tested this, so it may need some refinement, but I believe the idea is correct.

Comment: I actually need the full category not only the ids because I later need to know which parent is of which record - and to update for each record its parent id

Comment: OK. See edit. This is a work in progress as I have no data to test on, but I believe something like this is in the right direction.

Comment: what is new_list in "newlist for item in all_parent_ids" ?

Comment: I believe what will be returned is a bunch of nested lists and that will flatten the list.

Comment: The approach will return all the categories in the system, correct, but it seems to me that it will still make a db call to retrieve the parent of the parent

Comment: So the idea is it will return the immediate parent of each id in your original list, plus their parents, plus their parent's parents, and so on. Perhaps I misunderstood what you were after.

Comment: correct, but I would still need to build myself the "tree" model from it

Comment: Not sure what you quite mean by that, but you will get a list of parents, their parent's parents and so on. You can get all associated categories with those ids as I have shown in my last two lines of code. Or you could get categories for each sublist that is returned, if I get your meaning. What ends up being in `all_parent_ids`?

Comment: all_parent_ids is a flat list. what if I do: category.parent.parent? retrieving the parent of the parent will require db call

Comment: that's the thing. right now 3 but I want it to be dynamic

Comment: What if the function paired ids with category objects? Are you saying you need the parent ids paired with their children?

Comment: I am not sure how architecture wise it makes sense

Comment: I am not sure this is going to help, but I edited my answer. I'm wondering if passing one id at a time to the `get_categories` function would be what you want and the output will be a list of lists, a list of parents/grandparents/greatgrandparents/... for each id.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted, but actually I used it as a basic. I later created a map  and looped to connect parent and object. pure programming

Comment: OK. Well, I hope I was able to help at least some. If nothing else, you gave me something challenging to think about. All the best with the rest of your project.